# Mono<Flux> -> how to return ResponseEntity.NOT_FOUND?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have an app in Spring Boot and Webflux.
I don't know how to return `ResponseEntity.NOT_FOUND` when no values are returned from my DB?

Assumptions:
I have to return

```
Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<BackupResponse>>>
```

My code:

```
@Override
      public Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<BackupResponse>>> getRecentBackups(
          Integer lastHours, String protectionId, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return Mono.just(backupService.getRecentBackupsByProtectionId(lastHours, protectionId))
            .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
            .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
      }
```

Service method:

```
public Flux<BackupResponse> getRecentBackupsByProtectionId(Integer lastHours, String protectionId) {
    Instant lastAcceptableDate = Instant.now().minus(lastHours, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
    return backupsByDateRepository
        .findByProtectionIdAndCreatedGreaterThanEqual(protectionId, lastAcceptableDate)
        .map(backupMapper::mapBackupByDateToBackupResponse);
  }
```

Repository:

```
public interface BackupByDateRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<BackupByDate, MapId> {
Flux<BackupByDate> findByProtectionIdAndCreatedGreaterThanEqual(
      String protectionId, Instant created);
}
```

Unfortunately, `defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());` is not invoked when no values are return from DB and in this case I want to return 404 NOT_FOUND status. Is it possible in my case???

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `.switchIfEmpty` operator.